# PHP, HTML beautifier?

Tags: php, javascript, html, editor

can anyone tell me what program can beautify php, html, js. It can be commercial solution.
Thanx for any info

Comment: I find that bleach is a good way to beautify most PHP code.

Comment: You should consider handling PHP and HTML indentation separately. The two would require completely different parsers/tokenisers. For HTML output indentation, consider https://github.com/gajus/dindent.

Answer (score 9):

http://infohound.net/tidy/

http://www.phpformatter.com/

http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: nice. useful when working with poorly formatted 3rd party code.

Comment: Hi, but i was thinking about application not on someones site, i am circumspect so i don't know if my code will not be used someone else.