# Make it pretty using php

Tags: php, arrays, soap, styles

```
object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
  ["return"]=>
  string(43362) "[{"Searchstring":"?showitemlist=1&Keyword=blue&acctwebguid=12bad325-a118-4778-825a-cc7d5308e24f&orderby=ItemName%20DESC&requestguid=29E60B17-8601-4839-AD00-00DB0D45A2CB","Recordcount":15446},{"Maxretail":7.42000000,"Displayname":"","Suplitemno":"COA09B/K","Supplieritemid":"D7784D83-F63D-4219-BDB1-F7AE76F74CC8","Minretail":5.99000000,"Minqty":25,"Rushavailable":0,"Imagepath":"images/products/EA8E5917-F1D9-4089-BC09-DDE2FF03452F/medium/D7784D83-F63D-4219-BDB1-F7AE76F74CC8.jpg?_=1423597800","Imagepathsm":"images/products/EA8E5917-F1D9-4089-BC09-DDE2FF03452F/small/D7784D83-F63D-4219-BDB1-F7AE76F74CC8.jpg?_=1423597799","Prodtime":10,"Imagepathlg":"images/products/EA8E5917-F1D9-4089-BC09-DDE2FF03452F/large/D7784D83-F63D-4219-BDB1-F7AE76F74CC8.jpg?_=1423597800","Companyname":"Graphik Business Accessories","Displayno":"","Imagepathmd":"images/products/EA8E5917-F1D9-4089-BC09-DDE2FF03452F/medium/D7784D83-F63D-4219-BDB1-F7AE76F74CC8.jpg?_=1423597800","Shownopricing":0,"Itemname":"Zume Coaster Set"},{"Maxretail":50.38000000,"Displayname":"","Suplitemno":"7003-47","Supplieritemid":"F7374437-2DF5-4D4B-B654-32F7C7B8971E","Minretail":39.98000000,"Minqty":10,"Rushavailable":0,"Imagepath":"images/products/A0FB382C-C7AE-11D3-896A-00105A7027AA/medium/F7374437-2DF5-4D4B-B654-32F7C7B8971E.jpg?_=1438623367","addlImagesLarge":["images/products/A0FB382C-C7AE-11D3-896A-00105A7027AA/large/7003_47-7003_47bk_b_1.jpg?_=1438623368","images/products/A0FB382C-C7AE-11D3-896A-00105A7027AA/large/7003_47-7003_47bk_b_3.jpg?_=1438623368","images/products/A0FB382C-C7AE-11D3-896A-00105A7027AA/large/7003_47-7003_47bk_d.jpg?_=1438623369","images/products/A0FB382C-C7AE-11D3-896A-00105A7027AA/large/7003_47-7003_47bk_d_2.jpg?_=1438623369","images/products/A0FB382C-C7AE-11D3-896A-00105A7027AA/large/7003_47-7003_47bk_d_3.jpg?_=1438623370"],"Imagepathsm":"images/products/A0FB382C-C7AE-11D3-896A-00105A7027AA/small/F7374437-2DF5-4D4B-B654-32F7C7B8971E.jpg?_=1438623367","Prodtime":5,"Imagepathlg":"images/products/A0FB382C-C7AE-11D3-896A-00105A7027AA/large/F7374437-2DF5-4D4B-B654-32F7C7B8971E.jpg?_=1438623367","addlImagesSmall":["images/products/A0FB382C-C7AE-11D3-896A-00105A7027AA/small/7003_47-7003_47bk_b_1.jpg?_=1438623368","images/products/A0FB382C-C7AE-11D3-896A-00105A7027AA/small/7003_47-7003_47bk_b_3.jpg?_=1438623369","images/products/A0FB382C-C7AE-11D3-896A-00105A7027AA/small/7003_47-7003_47bk_d.jpg?_=1438623369","images/products/A0FB382C-C7AE-11D3-896A-00105A7027AA/small/7003_47-7003_47bk_d_2.jpg?_=1438623370","images/products/A0FB382C-C7AE-11D3-896A-00105A7027AA/small/7003_47-7003_47bk_d_3.jpg?_=1438623371"],"Companyname":"Leed&apos;s / Leeds","Displayno":"","Imagepathmd":"images/products/A0FB382C-C7AE-11D3-896A-00105A7027AA/medium/F7374437-2DF5-4D4B-B654-32F7C7B8971E.jpg?_=1438623367","addlImagesMed":["images/products/A0FB382C-C7AE-11D3-896A-00105A7027AA/medium/7003_47-7003_47bk_b_1.jpg?_=1438623368","images/products/A0FB382C-C7AE-11D3-896A-00105A7027AA/medium/7003_47-7003_47bk_b_3.jpg?_=1438623368","images/products/A0FB382C-C7AE-11D3-896A-00105A7027AA/medium/7003_47-7003_47bk_d.jpg?_=1438623369","images/products/A0FB382C-C7AE-11D3-896A-00105A7027AA/medium/7003_47-7003_47bk_d_2.jpg?_=1438623369","images/products/A0FB382C-C7AE-11D3-896A-00105A7027AA/medium/7003_47-7003_47bk_d_3.jpg?_=1438623370"],"Shownopricing":0,"Itemname":"Zoom&#xae; Audio Decibel Bluetooth Speaker"},.......
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP, HTML beautifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157877/php-html-beautifier)

Comment: Is this a question?

Comment: Yes I have been fighting this for a while. I need a way to transform this object into a nice html.

Comment: partially fixed

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var data = '[{"Maxretail":...,"Itemname":"Youth Chameleon T-Shirt"]';
var table = '<table><thead><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Image</th><th>More</th></thead><tbody>';
var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
$.each(obj, function() {
    table += '<tr><td>' + this['Itemname'] + '</td><td>' + this['Supplieritemid'] + '</td><td><img src="https://cdn.distributorcentral.com/' + this['Imagepath'] + ' alt="' + this['Itemname'] + '" /></td><td><img src="https://cdn.distributorcentral.com/' + this['addlImagesSmall'] + ' alt="' + this['Itemname'] + '" />' + this['addlImagesSmall'] + '</td></tr>';
});
table += '</tbody></table>';
document.getElementById("datalist").innerHTML = table;
```

});